# Add an image to touch location iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have an app that connects points in an array with lines, what I want to do next is to add a marker to every line's end points, I chose a red dot for that. But I can't figure out how to even start. The image should appear every time the user taps the screen, because that's when a new point is created. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`to your view with the following method as the GR's action. Supposing you're using e.g an image asset for your dot it would be:

```
-(void)screenTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [tap locationInView:self.view];

    UIImageView *redDotImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redDot"]];
    redDotImageView.center = tapLocation;

    [self.view addSubview:redDotImageView];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. This seems to be the best approach, however for some reason the method is not being called when I tap on the screen. I'm doing the drawing in a class that is a subclass of UIView, do you know if that might be causing the problem, I dont see why. I also placed the code withing my touchesBegan method and placed a breakpoint, but that portion is never called. I had to modify the last line of your code to add the subView because i'm in a subclass, so it looks like `[self addSubview:redDotImageView];`    Any ideas, thanks again man!

Comment: try adding `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: did you miss by mistake alloc in: `[UIImageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];`

Comment: ok, finally I got it working with your code, so thanks so much. I placed the code inside touchesEnded and now it displays the image correctly. I edited your answer to add the alloc that you missed in case someone uses the code later. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :) And thanks for noticing the missing alloc

Answer (score 0):

For example you can add gesture recognized to your view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addDotToTapPoint:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

then implement method addDotToTapPoint: to find point of tap:

```
- (void)addDotToTapPoint:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint pointOfTouch = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    //... draw circle or something
}
```

Second approach.
You can create your own subclass of UIView and implement method touchesBegan:withEvent:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pointOfTouch = [(UITouch *)[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    //... draw circle or something
}
```

In both cases You will get location of touch and can draw something in that point